# Can't get Compass running

Tags: compass-sass

I'm running Linux Mint 15.  I don't know if this a Path problem but I install compass with `gem install compass` and it says `1 gem installed`.  Then when I type `compass -v` I get the following:

```
The program 'compass' can be found in the following packages:
 * libcompass-ruby1.8
 * ruby-compass
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

**EDIT**

had to put `source ~/.bash_profile` inside my .bashrc file.  But now the error is

```
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build': /Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is strange.  I ended up wiping everything and re-installing RVM, Ruby, RubyGems, and Compass and now it all works fine.  Don't really know what happened.